# Export metrics calculation logic to a text file

Tags: business-objects

We are trying to export the logic to an Excel file. Reading through multiple levels of variables is quite a cumbersome process. Is there a piece of code that I can use to export the code to a text file?

Comment: Can you clarify? It's unclear to me what logic you want to export. The one in a WebI table?

Comment: I am trying to fetch, variables, sqls. pretty much everything that's underlying the GUI. I hope this makes sense